# Docker httpd apache and getting cgi-bin to execute perl script

Tags: apache, docker, perl

New to Docker and trying to get the cgi-bin working in a httpd image.  My Dockerfile is as follows.  The SED line adds the perl location to the first line of the example script that comes with the image:

```
FROM httpd:2.4.46
RUN sed -i '1c#!/usr/bin/perl' /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/printenv
```

I then build and run with:

```
docker build -t my-apache2 .
docker run -dit --name my-running-app -p 8080:80 my-apache2
```

I then navigate to `localhost:8080/cgi-bin/printenv` but instead of the script executing I get the code displayed as text.  It appears the httpd image comes with ScriptAlias enabled by default.  Any ideas please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to enable `mod_cgid`

```
FROM httpd:2.4.46
RUN sed -i '1c#!/usr/bin/perl' /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/printenv
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin/printenv
CMD httpd-foreground -c "LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so"
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.  The apache HowTo guide (https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html#configuring) does describe this requirement, but alas I'd completely overlooked it :(